# Load VIsual Basic Assembly in Unity3D

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, .net-assembly

I want to load Visual Basic Assembly File in Unity C# to read csv. The Assembly file is Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll, but the unity fails to load it, what can i do

Comment: Why do you need VB for that?

Comment: I wanted to do without regex so thought that would be the way, anyway i used TextAsset in Unity to read my csv file

Answer (score 0):

Not sure regarding your exact question, but try using StreamReader from System.IO, it's pretty easy and straight forward.